# How to auto-generate array key values if they are null (from a query)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

My application uses many arrays, and many sql queries. My issue is within this code:

I execute this query:

```
$select = "SELECT name, surname FROM table"

$query  = $connection->query($select);
$array  = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then, I pass the values into an array like this:

```
        $array_dump= array(
            array(
                array('name' => 'name'),
                array('content' => $array['name'])
            ),
            array(
                array('name' => 'surname'),
                array('content' => $array['surname'])
            ),
          )
```

In fact, this works properly, if you don't set error_reporting(). If I turn on, I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: surname in C:\AppServ\www\test.php on line 27

This actually happens, due the array was not set. In other words, surname value is empty.

**My trouble:**

I must use this methodology, but I can't use something like this (got error):

```
array(
    array('name' => 'name'),
    array('content' => (isset($array['surname']) ? $array['surname'] : '')
)
```

**My question**

As you see, this ain't an error properly, but that "Notice" should not appear (as INDEX is not defined...). Is there any way to set ALL array keys by default, from that *query*, even if the values are NULL, such as "surname" field? That would be the fastest solution. I've been looking for this, but got no answer.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not normal, even the surename in db is not present, it should assign empty value

Comment: Are you iterating over the query resultset? You should be using `$array[0]['name']`, and so on, where `0` is the index of the row you're parsing

Answer (score 0):

You should be iterating over the results and formatting them as necessary. Something like this:

```
$array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$array_dump = array();

foreach ( $array as $person ) {

    $tempArray = array();

    array_push($tempArray, array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'content' => $person['name']
    ));

    array_push($tempArray, array(
        'name' => 'surname',
        'content' => $person['surname']
    ));

    array_push($array_dump, $tempArray);    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set **ALL** possible array keys by default. But you can build array of default values based on predefined set of keys and merge it with main array. Somehow like this:

```
$a_keys = array('name', 'surname');
$a_defaults = array_combine($a_keys, array_fill(0, count($a_keys), 0));
$array = array_merge($a_defaults, $array);
...
```